# Boltzmann Law in moving fluids?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, research-level, brownian-motion, transport-phenomena

In my research, I am concerned with the analysis of systems which operate essential like this:

There is a tube, say of radius $r$. In this simplification in can be infinitely long. Air moves along it at a velocity $w$, and suspended in the air are particles (i.e. pollen or viral aeresols). Now, there is also a gravitational potential present, not necessarily parallel to the axis of the tube. My question is as follows, if a system in thermal equilibrium would follow the Boltzmann Law that
\begin{eqnarray}\rho(\vec{r}) \propto e^{-V(r)/kT}\end{eqnarray} then how does one approach the problem when in a moving fluid? Preferably, answers will not necessarily solve the problem but instead point me in the direction of the important principles in fluid mechanics and thermodynamics as i've really never studied fluids in detail before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Boltzmann distribution in a moving fluid is
$$
n(x,p) = \exp\left(\frac{\mu(x)-V(x)}{k_BT(x)}
-\frac{(\vec{p}-m\vec{u}(x))^2}{2mk_BT(x)}\right)
$$
where $n(x,p)$ is the particle distribution, $p$ is the momentum of the particle, and $m$ is the particle mass. Also, $\mu(x)$ is the chemical potential of the fluid, $T(x)$ the temperature, and $\vec{u}$ is the fluid velocity. The expression $n(x,p)$ is a local equlibrium distribution provided $\mu(x),T(x)$ and $\vec{u}(x)$ satisfy the equation of fluid dynamics (the continuity, and Euler/Navier-Stokes equation). Depending on your setup, you may be able to assume that $\mu,T$ and $\vec{u}$ are approximately spatially constant.

Also note that the local density
$$
\rho(x)=mn(x)=\int d^3p\, n(x,p)
\sim (2mk_BT(x))^{3/2}
\exp\left(\frac{\mu(x)-V(x)}{k_BT(x)}\right)
$$
is not affected by the fluid velocity (because $m\vec{u}$ is just a shift in $\vec{p}$).

Comment: How do you get to your first equation?

Comment: @MiguelCorreia  You either 1) check that this is a stationary solution of the Boltzann equation, or 2) appeal to Galilean invariance, or 3) view $u$ as a Lagrange multiplier that fixes the momentum of the fluid and maximizes entropy, or 4)  look it up in a text book on kinetic theory (eg vol X of Landau and Lifshitz).

Comment: I think your equation does not apply to OP's question. If you maximize entropy with Lagrange multiplier fixing local energy and momentum, and total number of particles  you see that you will not get your expression. You do however get your expression if you also impose constraint of fixing local density of particles, but this is not possible because you do not know it in this case. One must be a little more elaborate than just employing plain ideal gas kinetic theory, where the local density is a given and can be used to fix your normalization constant.

Comment: Not sure what you are refering to.  $\mu$ is the Lagrange multiplier that fixes the total number of particles, as usual. The only freedom you have is that sometimes people write $n\sim \exp(-(\epsilon_p-u\cdot p)/T)$ with $\epsilon_p=p^2/(2m)-\mu$. This differs by a shift in $\mu$, which is the difference between the chemical potentials in the Lab and local rest frame. In any event, I'm not reinventing the wheel. This is equ.(2.6) in Landau & Lifshitz.

Answer (score -1):

A moving fluid has non-zero mean velocity. Therefore, you'll have a kinetic component to the energy. So my guess would be that the density profile should instead obey
\begin{equation}
\rho(\vec{r}) \propto \exp\left(-{{m v^2(r)/ 2} + V(r) \over k T}\right),
\end{equation}
where $m$ is the mass of each air molecule and $v$ the fluid average speed.

If the fluid velocity is independent of the radius, which should be true for a non-viscous fluid, then $v(r) = v_0$ is a constant and we recover your expectation $\rho \propto \exp \left(-{V(r) \over k T}\right)$.

Comment: By Galilean invariance the only thing that matters is the velocity of the particles relative to the fluid velocity (equal to the mean velocity).

Comment: What Galilean invariance? It's a tube.

Comment: If you are an atom in a fluid, then you don't know that you live in a tube, you can only know the difference between your velocity and the velocity of surrounding atoms. This is a property of the Boltzmann equation.

Comment: You can only use that argument if there is translational invariance. More important than the walls of the tube here is the existence of local potential $V(r)$ which depends on the position and is not invariant under radial translation.

Comment: My proposal follows from the rough argument that under thermal equilibrium the probability of finding a particle at a given position is the Boltzmann factor $p(r) \propto \exp(- \beta E(r))$ where $E(r) = m v^2(r)/2 + V(r)$ is the average mechanical energy of an air molecule at $r$. If you want to use Boltzmann distribution you should note that most general solution to Boltzmann's equations is $f(r,v) = N \exp(- \beta ( m v^2 / 2 + V ) + \alpha \cdot v)$, where $N$ is a constant and $\beta$ and $\alpha$ may depend on $r$.

Comment: The average velocity of an air molecule in a fluid flow with velocity v is indeed equal to v, but the mean square velocity is not v^2, because the velocities have a Boltzmann distribution around v.

Comment: Your general solution is indeed right, but note that you now flipped notation relative your original answer. This v is not the fluid velocity, it is the velocity of the atoms. $\alpha=mu$ is related to the fluid velocity u. Then your answer is the same as mine, once you relate the overall normalizations.

Comment: Yes, I changed notation. $v$ as an argument of $f$ is the atomic velocity. $\alpha$ is related to the fluid velocity I agree.